# How to connect TFT screen to Rasberry PI?

Tags: screen

I have bought this TFT screen and I am not sure how to connect it with my Pi.

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B007SLDF7O?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007SLDF7O)

What other cables are required? And how to do it?

Comment: Now that the link from Amazon returns "SORRY we couldn't find that page" the question became unclear and useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This screen uses an RCA type input.

If you have an older style RPi (model A, model B), all you need is a [standard male-to-male RCA cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ST25WRM), as the older Pi has an RCA-style composite out.

[image]

If you have an RPi A+, B+ or RPi 2 model B, the composite out is inside the audio out, and you need a [3.5mm-to-RCA-male adapter](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/24-15489). Make sure that the adapter is of the correct type ( see the table in [this article](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/07/raspberry-pi-model-b-3-5mm-audiovideo-jack/) ). The cable link I provided has the right layout.

[image]

For power, the screen needs 12V or 24V. The RPi is not able to supply this. You will need a separate 12V DC power adapter and need to splice the wire of that adapter and connect the red wire and black wire to the red and black coming from the unit. If you buy a unit like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015GRCCIO), you don't have to cut the wire as it comes with an adapter with screw-on terminals, making your life much easier.

[image]